# Possible values for this specific line of variables.

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics, symmetric-polynomials

I have this line of numbers:

```
xy + z = xz + y = yz + x
```

I need to find out all the possible values of x, y and z in this equation.

Thank you!:)

My usual problem when guessing this:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 2

1 * 2 + 2 = 1 * 2 + 2 != 2 * 2 + 1
```

And it is like so with any values I try that first 2 equations are true, but the last one isn't.

Comment: If you let me guess, $x=y=z$ is obvious a solution.

Comment: If I think shortly, that yes. I am just thinking if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking cue from the results of @user133281, we have

$xy+z=xz+y$ implies $x(y-z) = y-z$, hence $y=z$ or $x=1$

$xz+y=yz+x$ implies $z(x-y) = x-y$, hence $x=y$ or $z=1$

$xy+z=yz+x$ implies $y(x-z) = x-z$, hence $x=z$ or $y=1$

So $x=y=z=1,2,3,4,...$ are the solutions.

However if one of the equalities does not hold, then

1. $x=1=>y\not=z=>$ either $x=z=>(1,y,1)$ or $y=1=>(1,1,z)$.
2. $y=1=>x\not=z>$ either $y=z=>(x,1,1)$ or $x=1=>(1,1,z)$
3. $z=1=>x\not=y>$ either $x=z=>(1,y,1)$ or $y=1=>(x,1,1)$

**Hence the final solutions** are $(x,y,z),(x,1,1),(1,y,1),(1,1,z)$ where $x,y,z$ are arbitrary..

Comment: I noticed that if x = y = z = 3 it will work aswell as with any number ( 3 * 3 + 3 = 3 * 3 + 3 = 3 * 3 + 3).

Comment: Yes, $x=y=z=1$ is not the only solution. See my answer.

Comment: OK! So it is that x = y = z! OK!

Comment: @user133281 you are right. I am updating my answer.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis I have updated my answer. Please check it for the final answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $xy+z=xz+y$ implies $x(y-z) = y-z$, hence $y=z$ or $x=1$.
Similarly, $x=y$ or $z=1$ and $x=z$ or $y=1$.

Now we distinguish cases based on the number of values that equal $1$.

Suppose none of the numbers equals $1$. Then all numbers are equal (because $y=z$, $x=y$ and $x=z$) and we find the solution $(x,x,x)$.

Suppose that only $x=1$. Then we find $x=y$ and $x=z$, contradiction.

Suppose that two of the numbers are $1$, say $x=y=1$. Then we also find $x=y$ (which is true), so we find the solution $(1,1,z)$.

If all numbers are $1$ we find the solution $(1,1,1)$.

In conclusion, the solutions are $(x,x,x)$ and $(1,1,z)$ with $x$ and $z$ arbitrary (and their permutations).

Comment: OK! Thanks... But I always get this problem when guessing possibilities. (I will post in the question)

Comment: Note that the possibilities are $x=1$ **or** $y=z$.  So first try $x=1$ and do not assume $y=z$.  Then you have to solve $y+z=yz+1$.  Try it! (without guessing).

Comment: OK! so y + z = y * z + 1. In this case I must make sure that counting outputs more than multiplying. Only case I see is that y = z = 1. So only way is that all numbers are 1?

Comment: How about (x,1,1), (1,y,1)?

Comment: (x,1,1), (1,y,1) are also valid.